# Documentation rooms still hanging around in chat

Tags: bug, documentation, chat

I stumbled over this randomly when trying to figure out why it only says there's 47 rooms when there are 52 pages of chatrooms.

Anyways, what I'm talking about can be found [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms?tab=all&sort=active&page=52) and [this](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127840/android-documentation-constraintlayout) is a single direct link to one room. It looks like every tag has a chatroom.

The JavaScript chatroom (not the regular one, [the documentation one](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/119021/javascript-documentation-design-patterns)) has had no messages **for over 400 days** and still isn't frozen. I assume this is something forgotten after the documentation was removed. (And I also guess the documentation chatrooms were designed to never be frozen, but none of them have been used.

While browsing through the rooms I also see at least three JS related rooms for documentation, none of which have been frozen.

The documentation chatroom with the most recent activity is the [node JS room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118916/node-js-documentation-mongodb-integration) after someone thought that was the place to ask questions. It came 290 days after the last message, and most of the messages are "hi" in some or another form.

As documentation was removed, shouldn't these rooms be too? They aren't used, so what's the point in keeping them around?

(I marked this post with [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bug) because the rooms are set to avoid being frozen. Meaning it's most likely a forgotten update after documentation was removed, hence a bug)

Comment: What is wrong with saying *hi* when you enter a room?

Comment: The point is that the only messages are hi. Not with seconds or minutes between, but days. There's no actual content worth preserving in those rooms

Comment: As if messages that no-one responds to are worth preserving  ...

Comment: IIRC we exempted topic/draft discussion rooms from the freezing/deletion rules on the grounds that they were supposed to function as, well, persistent discussion rooms. They'll be cleaned up by the end of the month as I continue working on shutting everything down.